# JSON Python reading/writing to a json file issue

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Code:

```
import json

numbers = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
filename = 'numbers.json'

with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
    json.dump(numbers, f_obj)
    json.dump(letters, f_obj)


with open(filename) as f_obj:
    numbers = json.load(f_obj)
    letters = json.load(f_obj)

print(numbers)
print(letters)
```

I would like to be able to read multiple lists which I have added to a json file and set them as separate lists which can be used later.

I don't mind having to adding a new line between each list in the json file and then reading it in line format.

Comment: what is your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not store them inside a global dictionary ?

```
import json

numbers = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
filename = 'numbers.json'

val={'numbers': numbers, 'letters':letters}

with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
    json.dump(val, f_obj)


with open(filename) as f_obj:
    val = json.load(f_obj)
    numbers = val['numbers']
    letters = val['letters']

print(numbers)
print(letters)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was usually scared of using dictionaries so I just used lists for everything but it seems that dictionaries may just be the way forward, thanks again.

Comment: you could also put all the lists inside one global list, but the dictionary makes it easier to retrieve elements by name ( instead of using indexes, and having to remember what index matches each list..)

Comment: PRMoureu, Could you do this with dictionaries containing dictionaries?

Comment: Sure, you just have to give a key and an object as value, and the value can be many kinds of objects in Python, string, integers, sets, classes, functions, dictionaries ... `val={'numbers': numbers, 'letters':letters, 'new_dict':{'a':[1,2,3]}}`. Next step : the keys don't need to be strings, you could use integers or other immutable types : `val = {1:numbers, 2:letters}`... dictionaries are your friends, don't fear them ;-)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the "val={'numbers': numbers, 'letters':letters, 'new_dict':{'a':[1,2,3]}}. " Specifically why's there's so many curly brackets.

Comment: i've just added a new item to the dict in the answer : `'new_dict':{'a':[1,2,3]}`. (If you want to make nested dictionaries, you will have nested brackets, cannot avoid this). Now if you want access the value of `a`, you need to call : `print(val['new_dict']['a'])`

Comment: Ok, I seem to understand now, I am a noob btw :)

Comment: no prob, just don't hesitate to open a console to play with new objects or new structures. i didn't link any documentation, [here you can find some examples](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)